# Use SQL Server trigger to insert into a backup table and link original to backup

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'm trying to implement the following logic in SQL Server:

every time data is inserted into `MainTable`, all this data should be also inserted into a backup table `MainTable_BACKUP`, and every row inserted into `MainTable` should have a foreign key `BackupRecordId` pointing to `MainTable_BACKUP`.

Can it be achieved using a trigger?

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_MainTable
ON MainTable
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MainTable_BACKUP 
        SELECT * 
        FROM INSERTED

    -- UPDATE INSERTED SET BackupRecordId = ??? somehow...
END
```

Comment: Note that although this can be done with a trigger, doing so will have a small, but negative impact on performance.  If that's not an issue, then go for it.  If that is an issue, consider using a stored procedure for inserts so that data is consistently inserted into the backup table and the main table within a transaction.  (The trigger method will enforce data integrity, though.  Using the SP method does allow for "back door" inserts that do not maintain data integrity.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can.

Assuming that you have an identity column named BackupRecordId on you MainTable_BACKUP table, you can create an after insert trigger like this

```
 Create Table MainTable
 (
    ID int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Description NVARCHAR(50),
    BackupRecordId int
 )

 Create table MainTable_BACKUP
 (
    BackupRecordId int IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [Id] int,
    Description NVARCHAR(50)
 )

 CREATE TRIGGER TRG_MainTable
    ON MainTable
    AFTER INSERT AS
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO MainTable_BACKUP([Id], Description) 
        SELECT [Id], Description FROM INSERTED

        UPDATE MainTable
        SET BackupRecordId = MP.BackupRecordId
        FROM MainTable
        INNER JOIN inserted i on i.Id = MainTable.Id
        INNER JOIN MainTable_BACKUP MP ON MP.Id = MainTable.Id
    END
```

You can try it with this:

```
insert into MainTable(Description) 
values ('Testing')

select * from MainTable
select * from MainTable_BACKUP
```